# Текст вылазит за div

Tags: jquery

Имеется код, определяющий самый высокий див и придающий высоту остальным, которые имеют класс column.

```
$(".column").each(function(){
    if ($(this).height() > max_height) { max_height = $(this).height(); }
});
$(".column").height(max_height);
```

Проблема заключается в том, что текст вылазит за пределы дива. Если код убрать, то с текстом проблем нет.

Снимок экрана

[image]